# What is wrong with this SQL query? A nonsensical error is occurring.

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Name = 'Name' AND Column = 'Column'
```

And I'm receiving the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Column = 'Column' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

I see no syntax error whatsoever. What is the problem?

Comment: and in Access, name is a reserved word, so squarebracket that too, who knows if you wont switch to Access :P

Comment: @nawfal *no one* ever switches to Access...

Comment: @nawfal -- is there a downsizing wizard for that? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Column` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to encapsulate it between ` chars:

```
AND `Column` = 'Column'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to have a column named column, which is a reserved word. Can you change it in your table? Rather than having to work around the design in every query that references it, you're better off fixing it if you can.